# Getting only the first name in an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array list like this: **ArrayList names = new ArrayList<>();** that stores people's first and last names when they are entered in different textbooks.

So when prompted to Joe Biden would be element number 1 then Barack Obama would be element number 2 in the array list. My question is that if it is possible to only get their first names like Joe from the array without getting Biden also?

Comment: Yes. But show us how you populate `names` now (share your current code).

Comment: yes `names.get(0).split("\\s+")[0]` would give you the desired result

Comment: String FN=txtFN.getText();

Comment: Good luck with Billy Bob Thornton and Iain Duncan Smith...store name components separately

Comment: ? The first name would still be `[0]`

Comment: Billy Bob Thornton's first name is "Billy Bob", not Billy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could just do

```
names.get(0).split("\\s+")[0]  //this would get you "Joe"
```

to get last name possibly do

```
names.get(0).split("\\s+")[1] //this would get you "Biden"
```

This way completely relies on the fact that you have a space in between their first and last name. and obviously edit the `0` to whatever index you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Each element will be sitting in the ArrayList as a String object.

You could use the Str.split() to split it into a array and get the last name.

Let's say your ArrayList

```
String str = names.get(0); //Joe Biden
String[] arr = str.split(" "); //this will create Array of String objects
System.out.println(arr[1]); will print Biden
```

However be careful using this method, it'll not work with people with 3 names or one name. People with one names will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. People with more than one name will print their last name incorrectly.

However you can overcome this by doing,

```
int arrLength = arr.length;
if(arrLength > 0) {
    System.out.println(arr[arrLength - 1]); //this will always print the last name, if the name isn't empty
}
```