# Single array[0] item is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

all devs smarter than me,

So basically I've got a name(first) input field, I want to let the user enter their first name and last name into that input. After that, I want to take the 2nd value(last name) and push the value into another input which is `hidden(display:none)`. So the code below, in theory, should do it

```
var array = [];

var fullname = $("#firstName").value.split(" ");

array.push(fullname);

$("#lastName").value = array[1];

alert(array[1])
```

For example iI i put in "First Last" as the name values in the firstName input and split and push to array, if I alert it `alert(array) or $("#lastName").value = array`, it does push the correct values, however when I try to alert or set only the 2nd part of the array[1] it keeps coming back as undefined!? Please enlighten me my friends.

Comment: use `.val()` instead of `.value`?

Comment: Your array will be like `[["the", "splitted", "value"]]`. You need to use `array = fullname` instead of `push()`

Comment: There's no need for the `array` variable. `fullname` is the array you want, and `fullname[1]` is their last name.

Comment: ...and also `val(fullname[1])` rather than `value = fullname[1]`.

Comment: This script shouldn't work at all... `.value` will be `undefined` hence `.value.split(" ")` will throw a type error...

Comment: Something similar you could see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249466/getting-only-the-first-name-in-an-array

Comment: @sangeetha not really - that's Java

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, jQuery uses the `val()` method to retrieve the value of a form element. Attempting to access the `value` property will return nothing.

That aside, your issue is because you're creating a nested array by pushing the result of `split()` (ie. an array) in to `array`:

```js
var fullname = $("#firstName").val().split(" ");

var array = [];
array.push(fullname);
console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="firstName" value="Foo Bar" />
```

Instead, just work with the result of `split()` directly, without calling `push()`:

```js
var fullname = $("#firstName").val();

var array = fullname.split(' ');
console.log(array[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="firstName" value="Foo Bar" />
```

This is obviously a basic example. You would also need to ensure that the resulting array has at least 2 elements in it.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

you have some syntax issues as:

```
var array = [];

var fullname = $("#firstName").val();
array=fullname.split(" ");
$("#lastName").val(array[1]);
alert(array[1]);
```

Comment: Aside from removing `value`, you've not changed the flawed logic.

Answer (score 0):

You want to push an array values to an array, instead of `array.push(fullname);`, use

```
array.push.apply( array , fullname);
```

or

```
array = array.concat(fullName);
```

Comment: A little overcomplicated when the original empty array definition isn't used

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know but you already gave the obvious answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, use `$("#lastName").val()` instead of `$("#lastName").value`. You are using `array[]` instead of array constructor(). E.g: `var a = array[1]` returns `1` which means value of `a
= 1`.

Kindly check the link: [Difference between new Array() and [ ]](https://coderwall.com/p/h4xm0w/why-never-use-new-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Your second statement and the link are contradicting each other. Also note that `[]` is a shortcut for `new Array()`, so any discrepancies between the two which you seem to believe exist are false.